# To identify the missing fields from a table

Tags: oracle

I have a table with a few columns already in it. Also I have a list of few fields . I wanted to check which fields are already in the table and which are not. I tried using the select statement by using the list of field I wanted to check. Is using select statement the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query yields the name and datatype for a table and schema for most versions of Oracle. You must have access to the dba tables which implies a user with DBA privileges. Or you can use all_tab_columns which anyone can select from.

```
select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision
from dba_tab_columns
where owner = 'yourSchema'
and table = 'yourTableName'
```

you can add more where clauses to fine tune what you want.  Is this what you want? It's not entirely clear.

To use this query you do not include the schema name and . in the table name as in:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where owner = 'TMCS' 
and TABLE_NAME='TMCS_BG_STI_Q213_DATA';
```

Comment: I tried the following and it didnt return anything.


select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='TMCS.TMCS_BG_STI_Q213_DATA';